# Python cgi - How can I use QUERY_STRING to upload file to FieldStorage form?

Tags: python-2.7, cgi, query-string

```
FieldStorage(None, None, 
  [FieldStorage('single', 'single_valid.smi', 'CC(=O)\tBAS 00162454'), 
   FieldStorage('Format_single', None, 'smi'), 
   FieldStorage('B', None, 'Create radar chart and image')
  ]
```

How can I rewrite it to `QUERY_STRING`?

That works:

```
os.environ["QUERY_STRING"] = "A=[None,Create radar chart and image]&SMI=CCC"
form=cgi.FieldStorage(keep_blank_values=1)
```

Comment: You should really format your code using the available tools. Currently this is really hard to read.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).